# Modifying an example( todos)

Tags: mongodb, meteor

to attempt to get a solid understanding of meteor and to couple it with mongoDB I'd like to ask one simple question.

The below is supplied with the example, used to fill the DB with information if it's empty. 
All I'm trying to do is add a line of code at the start that does something like  `Lists.remove();` at the begining. Simply so I can keep fooling around with the example, with the ability to restart meteor, resetting the information in the database. I'm just unsure what exactly is the data set. I know with one simple command like the one I listed above I can do this. I'm just looking at mongodb and meteor for the first time today, so thanks for being forgiving :)

```
// if the database is empty on server start, create some sample data.
Meteor.startup(function () {
if (Lists.find().count() === 0) {
var data = [
  {name: "Meteor Principles",
   contents: [
     ["Data on the Wire", "Simplicity", "Better UX", "Fun"],
     ["One Language", "Simplicity", "Fun"],
     ["Database Everywhere", "Simplicity"],
     ["Latency Compensation", "Better UX"],
     ["Full Stack Reactivity", "Better UX", "Fun"],
     ["Embrace the Ecosystem", "Fun"],
     ["Simplicity Equals Productivity", "Simplicity", "Fun"]
   ]
  },
  {name: "Languages",
   contents: [
     ["Lisp", "GC"],
     ["C", "Linked"],
     ["C++", "Objects", "Linked"],
     ["Python", "GC", "Objects"],
     ["Ruby", "GC", "Objects"],
     ["JavaScript", "GC", "Objects"],
     ["Scala", "GC", "Objects"],
     ["Erlang", "GC"],
     ["6502 Assembly", "Linked"]
     ]
  },
  {name: "Favorite Scientists",
   contents: [
     ["Ada Lovelace", "Computer Science"],
     ["Grace Hopper", "Computer Science"],
     ["Marie Curie", "Physics", "Chemistry"],
     ["Carl Friedrich Gauss", "Math", "Physics"],
     ["Nikola Tesla", "Physics"],
     ["Claude Shannon", "Math", "Computer Science"]
   ]
  }
];

var timestamp = (new Date()).getTime();
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
  var list_id = Lists.insert({name: data[i].name});
  for (var j = 0; j < data[i].contents.length; j++) {
    var info = data[i].contents[j];
    Todos.insert({list_id: list_id,
                  text: info[0],
                  timestamp: timestamp,
                  tags: info.slice(1)});
    timestamp += 1; // ensure unique timestamp.
  }
}}});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lists.remove() doesn't work because you have to specify something inside it, even nothing. Lists.remove({}) is what you want.

As explained in the docs http://docs.meteor.com/#remove:

> As a safety measure, if selector is omitted (or is undefined), no documents will be removed. Set selector to {} if you really want to remove all documents from your collection.

So:

```
Meteor.startup(function () {
  Lists.remove({});
  if (Lists.find().count() === 0) {
    console.log("Lists was empty");
    ...
```

Note: you will see the console.log in the terminal window you launched meteor from, not your browser console.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, I was reading through the docs as you mentioned this.

I knew I was along the right course with `Lists.remove();` - just needed `Lists.remove([]);`

Answer (score 1):

You could use `meteor reset` on the command line which [erases](http://docs.meteor.com/#meteorreset) your mongodb data